# Excel VBA Sub Routine is extremely Slow deleting a Range

Tags: performance, vba, excel

The following script is very slow and I'm not sure why.
The script works so if you copy and paste its a typo in the question.

```
Sub deleteData()
Dim wb as workbook
Dim ws as worksheet
Dim myCell as range
dim myRange as Range

with Application
 .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
 .ScreenUpdating = False
end with

Set wb = activeworkbook
set ws = wb.Sheets(1)
set myRange = ws.range("I15845:I64572")
set myCell = ws.range("I15845")

For each myCell in myRange 
  myCell.Delete
next myCell

with Application
 .Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
 .ScreenUpdating = True
end with

MsgBox "Procedure Complete!"

end sub
```

I have also tried

```
Sub deleteData()
Dim wb as workbook
Dim ws as worksheet
Dim myCell as range
dim myRange as Range

with Application
 .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
 .ScreenUpdating = False
end with

Set wb = activeworkbook
set ws = wb.Sheets(1)
set myRange = ws.range("I15845:I64572")

myRange.Delete

with Application
 .Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
 .ScreenUpdating = True
end with

MsgBox "Procedure Complete!"

end sub
```

I know this is a large range but it should not take hours to complete.

The data in the column is an anchored `countif`.

```
=countif($A$1:A1,A1)
```

So each cell would be:

```
=countif($A$1:A1,A1)
=countif($A$1:A2,A2)
=countif($A$1:A3,A3)
.
.
.
=countif($A$1:A10000,A10000)
```

Comment: The current question title states your concerns about the code, but what we need here is a summary of the *purpose* of the code.  Please see [ask] for examples, and [edit] the title accordingly.

Comment: This cannot be the complete code set and we don't have any good context for a review (as @TobySpeight mentions). The only other factor based on what is provided is `Application.EnableEvents=`[`True`|`False`] but still should not take literal hours to complete. Also, providing us with the actual time to complete (still don't believe this should be "hours") would be helpful.

Answer (score 3):

`COUNTIF()` is slow.  A few `COUNTIF()` statements in a worksheet can be okay, but thousands of them will result in a glacial spreadsheet.

Here is a way to replace your `COUNTIF()` statements:

1. Sort Column A.
2. In Column B, have each cell check if the corresponding cell in column A is equal to the cell above it in column A.  If no, put 1 in column B's cell.  If yes, set column B's cell equal to 1 + the value in the cell above it in column B.
3. In Column C, have each cell check if the corresponding cell in column A is equal to the cell **below** it in column A.  If yes, let the cell in column C be an empty string.  If no, set column C's cell equal to column B's cell.
4. (Optional)  In Column D, have each cell check if the corresponding cell in column C is an empty string.  If no, set column D's cell equal to column C's cell.  If yes, set column D's cell equal to the cell below it in column D.